# Oracle - loop through select statements until result is found

Tags: sql, oracle

I regularly need to search multiple tables for exact or like matches of a given value. The `SELECT` statements are always the same, but the value I search for is always different.

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE first_name = 'foobar';
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE job_title LIKE 'foobar%';
SELECT * FROM departments WHERE department_name LIKE '%foobar';
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE city LIKE '%foobar%';
```

I don't want to create a `VIEW` or `SELECT` (with `UNION`) because I only want to execute each query until the first result is found. If I find a result, stop, as not to cause unnecessary execution overhead.

How can I pass a parameter and loop through these statements using PL/SQL? Nested exception blocks?

In my environment, I expect to find either a result in only one table, or no results at all. My database is Oracle 10g (spare me), and I'm using SQL Developer 4.1.5.

Comment: Obviously you are selecting from different tables (Or are you??? Are you in fact looking at four different tables that hold SIMILAR data, just the opposite of the example you gave here) - so, you are selecting from different tables... so what kind of output do you really need? How is that output consumed? Does it become an input to further processing, and if so, how? Do you just need to display a row (from a yet-undetermined table) on screen for a user to read?

Comment: I'm searching in multiple tables. I believe `SELECT *` is causing confusion. For simplicity, assume that each query selects a consistently named field, `SELECT myNumber`, from each subsequent table. The output, `myNumber`, should display on screen and is not used as input for any other process.

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect this important additional information - otherwise readers will be confused. (Many readers skip the Comments, so they won't see your clarification.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.

`COALESCE()` is a SQL Standard function which Oracle implemented as required by the standard. The function takes one or more arguments, all of the same data type (otherwise the parser will throw an error), and it returns the first non-NULL argument, or NULL if all arguments are NULL.

Importantly, the query engine will compute the first argument, and if it is not NULL, it will return it **and it will not compute the other arguments.** If the first argument is NULL but the second isn't, it will return the second argument and it will stop. This is called "short-circuit evaluation."

2.

A scalar subquery is a query that returns a single column and a single row (if it returns more than a row where it was supposed to be a **scalar** query you will get a runtime error) - or it may return no rows. Scalar subqueries are often used where "expressions" in general may be used; in those cases, the value from the one-row, one-column returned by the subquery is used as the needed "expression". If the "value" returned is NULL, or if the subquery doesn't return any rows, then the expression will be NULL.

3.

You can use these observations for a solution to your problem. **Warning** though: you said your "search" argument can only be found in one table. If it is found in one table, but the corresponding value you must extract is NULL, then COALESCE won't know that should be the end of the search, and it will still compute all the scalar subqueries.

Here is an example of using this idea. Since I don't have your tables, I wrote it for the EMP and DEPT tables in the SCOTT schema. The input is a number, I hard-coded it but you can make it a bind variable (and you can write more complicated WHERE clauses). I search for the employee name where the employee number is 10, and if not found, I want the department name where the department number is 10.

```
select coalesce (
                  (select ename from emp  where empno  = 10),
                  (select dname from dept where deptno = 10)
                ) as name from dual;

NAME         
--------------
ACCOUNTING
```

Answer (score 3):

A SQL query returns a fixed set of columns.  So, your structure presumes that all the tables have the same columns.  I doubt this is the actual case, so let me assume that you know this and that you are using `SELECT *` as a shorthand.

You cannot short-circuit SQL queries.  But, you can arrange them so basically nothing gets done.  The idea is to use `NOT EXISTS` in a step-wise fashion.  This should be quite fast when the underlying table has data, so the CTE logic is actually skipped.

Here is a method using CTEs

```
with e as (
      SELECT *
      FROM employees
      WHERE first_name = 'foobar'
     ),
     j as (
      SELECT *
      FROM jobs
      WHERE job_title LIKE 'foobar%' AND
            NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM e)
    ),
    d as (
     SELECT *
     FROM departments
     WHERE department_name LIKE '%foobar' AND
           NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM e) AND
           NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM j)
    ),
    l as (
     SELECT *
     FROM locations WHERE city LIKE '%foobar%' AND
           NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM e) AND
           NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM j) AND
           NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM d)
    )
SELECT e.* FROM e UNION ALL
SELECT j.* FROM j UNION ALL
SELECT d.* FROM e UNION ALL
SELECT l.* FROM l ;
```

Comment: @KaushikNayak Yes, I believe they were reciprocating with more shorthand. This is a cool solution, thank you, Gordon.

Comment: This may be a good approach. However, the check in the WHERE clause for `d`, for example, should verify that both `e` and `j` are empty. As currently written, if `e` is not empty then `j` will be empty, and then `d` will be run even though that is not necessary. Moreover: since the optimizer can't know at compilation time whether the first (or the second, etc.) query will succeed, it is not clear if the third and fourth queries will not be run, even if a match is found in the first or second query. Something to **test** for sure!

Comment: @mathguy Yes, additional `AND NOT EXISTS` would be required. This solution unfortunately does not account for the execution order of each select statement, and may run a costly piece of the `WHERE` clause before checking `AND NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: @mathguy . . . I don't see what multiple exists are necessary.  If `j` is empty then `d` should be as well, so just checking `d` does what I want.  There could be an issue with the optimizer filtering before executing the subquery.  That would surprise me because the subquery has no correlation clause, so Oracle should only evaluate it once.

Comment: If `j` is empty, why should `d` be empty as well? Consider this situation: there is an employee with name `foobar`. This is picked up by `e`. So `j` will be empty automatically, due to the NOT EXISTS condition. Now there is a department named foobar. Why would this NOT be picked up by `d`? `j` being empty is a necessary condition for `d` to **do** pick up this row!